# Is there a provision for PF in ns3 for wimax

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, ns-3

Can we implement packet scheduling algorithms in NS3 for WIMAX? If so what is the best reference for it? i have a google-group discussion link for LTE implementation but i wanted to know that if it works with WIMAX or not.

[PF in LTE using NS3](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ns-3-users/I8bvHrl-TXA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are such capabilities. Please refer to the documentation on [Scheduling References](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/wimax.html#scheduling-services)

Comment: I was thinking about implementing  RR( round robin )

Comment: You can use what is already implemented as basis of a simple Round Robin.